# How find $x$ in a right triangle $ABC$ (${\measuredangle}A=90^\circ$) where ${\measuredangle}DBC={\measuredangle}DCA=x$,${\measuredangle}BAD=5x$?

Tags: geometry

In a right triangle $ABC$ (${\measuredangle}A=90^\circ$) taken in point $D$ such that $BD=AC$, ${\measuredangle}DBC={\measuredangle}DCA=x$,${\measuredangle}BAD=5x$. How find $x$?

Comment: Regarding your comment, can I interpret it in the following way? The suggested answer (in the book) is x = 15, but you can show that it is true only when the triangle is isosceles. Maybe you can share your finding by answering your own question (partially).

Comment: I myself solved for isosceles triangle and I got x=15. In the book, there was no answer.

Comment: How about post your (special cased) work and maybe we can work together?

Comment: Draw a circle with a radius of | AC | and centered at point B. Draw the perpendicular bisector of the side AC. This circle and this bisector intersect precisely in point D. So  $| \angle CBD|=| \angle DCA|=15^  \circ$  and $| \angle BAD|=5 \cdot 15^ \circ =75^ \circ$.

Comment: you can prove if it is not in such case,there is no solution. if $B<45°$, construction $BA'C', A'B=A'C'=AC, C' is on AC$, then let $CBD=15°$, you can prove $DCA>15°,BAD<75°$, so when D is move up, you prove $BAD$ and $DAC$ is decreasing.same method for $B>45°$

Comment: @chenbai Unable to follow your construction. C' is clearly stated on AC (ie between A and C), but where is A'?

Comment: @Mick ,I made a mistake and will post a solution soon.

Comment: @piteer Like I told you, if we can work together, we can have the problem solved. See the other answer of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is geo method to prove that only one solution for this question.

Assume we already know the solution of $ x=15°$

then if $\measuredangle B< 45°$ ,see picture below:

[image]

note $\angle BDC= \angle DCA$, so $AC$ tangent $BDC$ circumcircle $K$ ,and $BD=AC$ which means $D$ is intersect point of two circles.(ie, orange and blue)

$M$ is midpoint of $BC, A'M \perp BC ,(A',L)=A'M \cap $circle $MC.KC\perp AC, K=KC\cap A'M,L,K$is the circumcenter of $BD'C$ and $BDC.  D' $ is the solution of $A'BC$ so it is also the intersect point point of two circles( green and brown).since $\measuredangle C >45° \implies LM>KM \implies \stackrel{\frown}{BDC}$ out $\stackrel{\frown}{ BD'C} ,BD'>BD \implies  \measuredangle DBC>\measuredangle D'BC =15°. $

edit2:
to prove $\angle BAD< \angle BA'D'$ it is hard to explain by geometry so we set parameter $p=\dfrac{1}{\tan{C}}\le 1,MC=1.MB=-1 \implies k_{AD}=\dfrac{p(1+2p^2-\sqrt{p^4+p^2+1})}{1-p^2\sqrt{p^4+p^2+1}}$

$ k_{AD}$ can be postive, but in this case $\measuredangle BAD < \measuredangle BA'D'$. so we only care $ k_{AD} <0$. ie. $p^2\sqrt{p^4+p^2+1}>1$, in this case, $ k_{AD}$ is mono increasing function of $p$.

to make easy, we prove $f(p)=\dfrac{(1+2p^2-\sqrt{p^4+p^2+1})}{p^2\sqrt{p^4+p^2+1}-1}$ is mono decreasing function.

$x=p^2, f(p)=f(x)=\dfrac{(1+2x-\sqrt{x^2+x+1})}{x\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-1}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}-\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{x}+1}+2}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\dfrac{1}{x}}$

it is trivial $\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\dfrac{1}{x} >0$ is mono increasing function.

$g(z)=z-\sqrt{z^2+z+1}, g'(z)=1-\dfrac{z+\dfrac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{z^2+z+1}}>0 \implies g(z)$ is mono increasing.$\implies g(\dfrac{1}{x})$ is mono decreasing function.$\implies f(p)$ is mono decreasing.

so   $ k_{AD}$ get max when $p=1 \implies \measuredangle BAD \le \measuredangle BA'D'$

(end edit2)

we done.

when $\measuredangle B>45°$ see picture below:

[image]

it is same way that we prove $\measuredangle DBC <15° $ and $\measuredangle BAD>75°$

Comment: I have an updated solution posted, 10 hours after your work.

Answer (score 1):

W.l.o.g. you may assume the following coordinates:

$$A=(0,0)\quad B=(a,0)\quad C=(0,1)\quad D=(b,c)$$

If you define $d:=\cos(x)$ then you can compute the [cosines of multiple angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Multiple-angle_formulae) using a [Chebyshev polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) as

$$\cos(5x)=T_5(d)=16d^5 - 20d^3 + 5d\;.$$

The [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) of two vectors is proportional to the cosine, so you can write the first angle equality as

$$\frac{\langle D-B,C-B\rangle^2}{\lVert D-B\rVert^2\cdot\lVert C-B\rVert^2} = d^2$$

and likewise for the other two angle conditions, the last of which will make use of $\cos^2(5x)$ on its right hand side. The equal length condition is simply expressed as

$$\lVert B-D\rVert^2 = \lVert A-C\rVert^2\;.$$

By using squares in all steps involving the lengths of some vector, we managed to avoid introducing square roots into our equations. So now you have four polynomial equations in four variables, which can be rewritten as

\begin{align*}{}
- a^4 d^2 + a^4 + 2 a^3 b d^2 - 2 a^3 b -  a^2 b^2 d^2 + a^2 b^2 -  a^2 c^2 d^2 \\{}
+ 2 a^2 c -  a^2 d^2 - 2 a b c + 2 a b d^2 -  b^2 d^2 -  c^2 d^2 + c^2 &= 0
\\[2ex]{}
- b^2 d^2 -  c^2 d^2 + c^2 + 2 c d^2 - 2 c -  d^2 + 1 &= 0
\\[2ex]{}
-256 a^2 b^2 d^{10} + 640 a^2 b^2 d^8 - 560 a^2 b^2 d^6 + 200 a^2 b^2 d^4 - 25 a^2 b^2 d^2 \\{}
+ a^2 b^2 - 256 a^2 c^2 d^{10} + 640 a^2 c^2 d^8 - 560 a^2 c^2 d^6 + 200 a^2 c^2 d^4 - 25 a^2 c^2 d^2 &= 0
\\[2ex]{}
a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 + c^2 - 1 &= 0
\end{align*}

Now in theory you could use your favorite computer algebra system to compute solutions for these. Perform some extra checks, like ensuring that the orientations match your expectations, and you can obtain possible $x=\arccos(d)$ from the remaining solutions. In practice, my [sage](http://sagemath.org/) is still busy trying to solve this system. I'll update this answer if it manages to come up with a solution.

While I still don't have a list of *all* solutions, I can confirm that you have a solution of this system for

$$a=1\qquad b=1-\tfrac12\sqrt3\qquad c=\tfrac12\qquad
d=\tfrac12\sqrt{\sqrt3 + 2}\qquad x=15°$$

as your comment indicated. However, strictly speaking you have $\angle DBC=\angle DCA=-15°$ here, but $\angle BAD=+75°$. So this is a solution except for the orientation of the angles.

[image: Figure of the first known solution]

Comment: i have solution if triangle is  isosceles $x=15^o$

Comment: I thought the arrangement of points gives us equidiagonal quadrilateral.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT a solution. It is just some of the interesting findings in the course of seeking the required solution.

I have to give that up because I cannot think of any method of incorporating the given 5x into my work.

I just hope that someone can have an elegant geometric solution and some of my findings maybe useful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Upvote for the only decent images on this page so far

Comment: @Ragnar Thankyou for the support.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the OP, if we can show that the line through D parallel to AB is the perpendicular bisector of AC, then x = … = 15 degrees. The following shows how this can be achieved.

Constructions:-

(1) Draw the rectangular coordinate system X’DX and Y’DY.

(2) Draw a circle using D as center, radius = DB. Then AC = DB = DY = DY’.

(3) Join AB and also join YB such that YB cuts DX at P (as shown in the first figure below.)

[image]

Move on to the second figure.

[image]

From $\measuredangle Y’DP + \measuredangle PBY’ = 90 + 90 = 180$, Y’DPB is a cyclic quadrilateral. [opp. angles supp.]

Then, r = q = p [angles in in the same segment + base angle isosceles triangle]

Therefore, PY = PY’.

Move on to the third figure.

By properties of isosceles triangle, m = n.

[image]

Right shift AC along AB  to A'D'C' where A' is the intersection of AB and Y'P; (similar for C').

The light yellow triangle is congruent to the dark yellow triangle. [ASA]

Therefore, A'D' = D'C'.

Because, A'D'C' is just the image of AKC; where K is the intersection of AC and X'X, AK = KC.

Thus, X'X is the perpendicular bisector of AC.

The required result then follows. (See OP's comment.)